# Session in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to ask this question if how can we make a session in code igniter specially in logging in and logging out on the account. I want to know the step by step following the MVC of code igniter.

Comment: Go to https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html for more information on Sessions in Codeigniter. Or are you expecting that we build your application for you?

Comment: All the docs can be found here now http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using my code as an example you can do this i have a controller called iris.php and a model called script.php. i use the iris to call and make use of the script model.

```
    class Iris extends CI_Controller {
function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('script');
    $this->load->model('alert');
}
public function index()
{ $this->load->view('index');
}
 public function login_in()
{
    $login = $this->script->check_login();
    if($login->num_rows() == 1){
      foreach ($login->result_array() as $row) {
        $newdata = array(
        'fullname'  => $row['fullname'],
        'email'     => $row['email'],
        'member_id' => $row['member_id'],
        'transtatus'=>$row['transtatus']
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
      }
      redirect('iris/user_home');
    }else
    {
        $data = array('alert'=>$this->alert->log_alert());
        $this->load->view('common/header');
        $this->load->view('login',$data);
        $this->load->view('common/footer');
    }
}`
```

i first load the model script model under the constructor and in the login function of the iris controller i called the function in the script `$login=$this->script->check_login();`
in the script.php we have the following code.

```
    {public function check_login(){
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
          $query = "SELECT * FROM `iris_user`
      WHERE`email`=? AND`password`= ? ";
          $result = $this->db->query($query, array($email, $password));
          return $result;
      }
```

remember you have to have loader the session class helper form the application/config/autoload.php file in the CIfolder

```
 $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

the session is alway start once it has been autoloaded, but can be destroyed when maybe creating a logout function.
also note when adding to the session data variable to access the session variable you will have to use the name that was used when declaring the session variable. e.g to access the fullname you would do this in code

```
echo $_SESSION['fullname'];
```

Answer (score 4):

At the login time after executing query  set session data in set_userdata  function and passing data array whos you want to set.

$this->session->set_userdata('session data here');

And at the time of logout you have to call unset_userdata function and passing array of array whos you have to set at login time.

$this->session->unset_userdata('session data here');

Answer (score 1):

In the controller load library session :

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Use below sentence for session create :

```
$this->session->set_userdata("session_name",session_value);
```

For Session Unset:

```
$this->session->unset_userdata("session_name");
```